# How to get user specific recommended videos based on specific channel

Tags: youtube-api

How to get user specific recommended videos based on specific channel like - **nba, nationalgeographic** using YouTube API?

I am using the below API to get recommended videos.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/recommendations?v=2&key=&access_token=

`key` -> I am passing my developer key

`access_token` -> I am passing authentication token.

Its returning me recommended videos of specific user. But I need recommended videos of specific channels like nba, nationalgeographic.

Can anyone please help for this.

Comment: I think you might have your terminology mixed up here. What do you mean by "recommended videos of specific channels"? Is there something specific in the web interface at http://www.youtube.com/user/NationalGeographic that corresponds to what you're talking about, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but in case anyone googling this comes across this answer, a workaround until there is a full recommendation API in YouTube API v3 is to use the Activity List feature, then just go through the results looking for "type": "recommendation":

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&home=true&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

(don't forget to use an auth token for a user for this to work)

Comment: The ```home``` parameter has now been deprecated :(

Comment: @Supertecnoboff have you found a workaround to that?